# tkinter save zip file with asksaveasfile

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm finalizing a Tkinter GUI. I want to be able to export the results in a zip file.
the export contains several images and a xlsx/csv

I've managed to create a ZIP file and save it in the current directory with several images and I can also save a single file with `asksaveasfilename` in a specific directory. I however haven't managed to get it to actually save the ZIP file in a asked location or include a xlsx/csv in the ZIP file together with the PNGs

In the MWE below I was able to just save the ZIP file

Thanks in advance!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import zipfile
import io
from tkinter.filedialog import *

from PIL import ImageTk, Image  # type "Pip install pillow" in your terminal to install ImageTk and Image module
import random

window=Tk()
window.geometry("400x250")

image1 = Image.open('Images/aa.ico')
image2 = Image.open('Images/aa.ico')
image3 = Image.open('Images/aa.ico')

images = (image1, image2, image3)
image_names = ("nameone", "nametwo", "namethree")
def save():
    zip_file_name = "export.zip"
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, mode="w") as zf:
        for i in range(len(images)):
        # i = 1
            buf = io.BytesIO()
            images[i-1].save(buf, "PNG")
            images[i-1].close()
            img_name = "fig_{}.png".format(image_names[i-1])
            zf.writestr(img_name, buf.getvalue())
      

button = Button(window, text ="save ZIP", command = lambda:save())
button.pack()



mainloop()
```

the code i have used before to actually save with  `asksaveasfilename` is

```
def save():

    a = image1.filename = asksaveasfilename(
                                           title = "Select file",
                                           defaultextension=".png",
                                           filetypes=[('PNG', ".png")],
                                           )
    image1.save(a)
```

Comment: `asksaveasfilename` returns the selected file, `asksaveasfile` returns a file object. Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile

Comment: thanks, but i think i should be using `asksaveasfilename` here correct?

Comment: As a side note, it would appear that `lambda` is unnecessary here....unless you're planning to pass arguments to `save`.....why not just use `command=save`?